# Mapped Drive Storage Size Matches my Windows Drive?

Tags: windows-10, storage, sharepoint, mapped-drive

I have a couple of drives mapped to a SharePoint site. When I open Windows 10 Explorer and look at the details of my Windows (C:) drive, it tells be there are "4.77 GB free of 66.7 GB".

When I look at the details of any of the drives I have mapped to SharePoint, I see the exact same storage information as I do when I look at my C: drive (4.77 GB free of 66.7 GB).

Is there something funky going on, or am I just misunderstanding how mapped drives really work?

Comment: I’m not that familiar with SharePoint – how exactly do you map a drive?

Comment: a drive mapping is a sort of shortcut, so there is nothing funky going on. You just made a shortcut of your C:\ drive to your sharepoint site. 
The actual size of the disk will be the same on the mapped item.

Comment: You map it as you would any other drive, except you would paste the SharePoint document library URL in the folder field.

Comment: OK. I see. So the info about the available storage has nothing to do with the mapped drives. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) ("Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning") is used to create the drive mapped to the SharePoint URL.

From Microsoft's [KB2386902: WebDav mapped drive reports incorrect drive capacity](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2386902):

> Cause:
>
> ...WebDAV protocol doesn’t support querying server’s disk capacity.
> With this constrain of WebDAV protocol, **Windows client sets WebDAV
> mapping drive’s capacity the same as its System Drive**.
>
> Resolution:
>
> This is by design. A WebDAV mapped drive's capacity is set to match
> the client machine's System drive capacity. This means that the
> capacity you get from a WebDAV mapped drive is the same as your local
> System drive. System drive is where Windows is installed.
>
> Example:
>
> On a Windows client:
>
> System drive C:\
>
> Free disk space: 39.9 GB
>
> Used Disk Space: 11.2 GB
>
> WebDAV mapped drive Y:\
>
> Free disk space: 39.9 GB
>
> Used Disk Space: 11.2 GB

Comment: This is funny when C: drive has 3GB left, your mapped drive has 90GB left, and Windows won't let you copy a 3.1GB file to the mapped drive because there is not enough space

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's statement is incorrect.

As shown in the [RFC 4331](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4331) standard it is actually supported. Microsoft just didn't implement it.

Comment: I suspect that KB article predates RFC 4331 by several years, so it _wasn't wrong_ at the time – they just never bothered to update the Windows client later.